# why can't i hide the node_module file by .gitignore after applying node_modules/ or /node_modules on nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules, gitignore

My .gitignore file is on as the same root as .git folder

[image: here my project folder view]

i have also tried out different format like 'node_modules/' '/node_modules'
though it's hiding my .env file.
But gitignore still not hiding my node_modules folder

[image]

I have also tried by uninstalling the node_modules > updated the .gitignore file > npm install. Still it doesn't work. What should i do now?

Comment: In what tool are you trying to hide them?  `.gitignore` doesn't affect your IDE.

Comment: i'm using vs code for server side work(with node js).and after git push the 'node_modules' file is still showing on my git repository.Hope you understood

Comment: How do you know?  The "explorer" view in VSCode should you the files on disk, not in the repo.  And git doesn't store folders -- just files.

Comment: "still showing" does that mean you accidentally committed node_modules before adding it to `.gitignore`? Note that `.gitignore` only **ignores** files. It does not remove files from your repository

Answer (score 0):

Try using **node_modules/***

This will tell git to ignore all files and folders inside the node modules folder.
Also make sure to check it by adding a dependency and using the command

```
git status
```

It will give you a list of all changed files.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because your git repository is already tracking your 'node_modules' folder. Try removing the folder and commiting the change, then reinstall your node modules with `npm i`. The folder should then remain untracked and will appear greyed out in VS Code.